# remove JSON key value, if the value inside the object exists before

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, javascript-objects

So, I have a json object where the keys are random and the values repeat sometimes. I need to find a way to delete the repeated values with the key. If it is a json array I need to remove a specific value from the json array.
For example if my JSON file is as below:

```
  {
  "modelhelloamazingIssue": {
    "modelhelloamazingIssueSevere": {
      "nameText": "Name",
      "helloAnalysisType": [
        "Normal",
        "Mild",
        "Moderate",
        "Severe"
      ],
      "helloText": "hello",
      "abouthellosolo": "hello solo is a serious hello disorder that causes you to stop amazing during hello. It's important to understand the signs and symptoms.",
      "noteText": "This is not a medical diagnosis and you may want to talk to your doctor.",
      "buttonText0": "Next steps"
    },
    "modelhelloamazingIssueMild": {
      "nameText": "Name Example",
      "helloAnalysisType": [
        "Normal",
        "Mild",
        "Moderate",
        "Severe"
      ],
      "helloText": "hello",
      "abouthellosolo": "My god this is so cool.",
      "noteText": "This is not a medical diagnosis and you may want to talk to your doctor.",
      "buttonText1": "Next steps"
    }
  }
}
```

my Expected output of the new JSON file I create will be like this.

```
{
  "modelhelloamazingIssue": {
    "modelhelloamazingIssueSevere": {
      "nameText": "Name",
      "helloAnalysisType": [
        "Normal",
        "Mild",
        "Moderate",
        "Severe"
      ],
      "helloText": "hello",
      "abouthellosolo": "hello solo is a serious hello disorder that causes you to stop amazing during hello. It's important to understand the signs and symptoms.",
      "noteText": "This is not a medical diagnosis and you may want to talk to your doctor.",
      "buttonText0": "Next steps"
    },
    "modelhelloamazingIssueMild": {
      "nameText": "Name Example",
      "abouthellosolo": "My god this is so cool."
    }
  }
}
```

So far I have tried the following approach in my javascript, I don't know what keys are present so I need to parse them individually. I can not write to the expected output file. I'm able to find the duplicate values but not sure how to remove it from the file.
I'm using **delete key** but still it's not deleting from the file.

```
const fs = require('fs');
var array = [];


function parse() {
    let json = require('/home/ashutosh/Downloads/latest-night-strings.json')
    var keys = Object.keys(json)
    getAllValues(keys, json)


    let data = JSON.stringify(json);
    fs.writeFileSync('/home/ashutosh/Desktop/awesome.json', data);
    console.log(data)
    // print(json)

}


function getAllValues(key, jsonObject) {

    for (var i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
        console.log(typeof jsonObject[key[i]] == 'object');

        if (typeof jsonObject[key[i]] == 'object') {

            let myAnotherObject = jsonObject[key[i]]
            var keys = Object.keys(myAnotherObject)
            getAllValues(keys, myAnotherObject)
        }

        if (typeof jsonObject[key[i]] == 'string') {

            if (array.includes(jsonObject[key[i]])) {

                //    Already contains the value so delete the json key value from the file...

                console.log("deleting duplicate keys" + key[i] + " with value" + jsonObject[key[i]]);
                //"noteText": "This is not a medical diagnosis and you may want to talk to you doctor.",
                var isDeleteSuccess = delete key[i]
                console.log("isDeleteSuccess " + isDeleteSuccess)


            } else {

                array.push(jsonObject[key[i]])
            }

            console.log(jsonObject[key[i]]);

        }
    }
}

parse()
```

Comment: `buttonText0` and `buttonText1` are different keys..

Comment: yes, and only one of them should appear. which ever was encountered first should have that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Update: OP doesn't care about keys, so to just remove duplicate
> values, and then of course the associated key, below is an example
> using Set's.

Updated working snippet below ->

```js
const data = {"modelhelloamazingIssue":{"modelhelloamazingIssueSevere":{"nameText":"Name","helloAnalysisType":["Normal","Mild","Moderate","Severe"],"helloText":"hello","abouthellosolo":"hello solo is a serious hello disorder that causes you to stop amazing during hello. It's important to understand the signs and symptoms.","noteText":"This is not a medical diagnosis and you may want to talk to your doctor.","buttonText0":"Next steps"},"modelhelloamazingIssueMild":{"nameText":"Name Example","helloAnalysisType":["Normal","Mild","Moderate","Severe"],"helloText":"hello","abouthellosolo":"My god this is so cool.","noteText":"This is not a medical diagnosis and you may want to talk to your doctor.","buttonText1":"Next steps"}}};

function removeDuplicateValues(obj) {
  const dups = new Set();
  function inner(o) {
    const needSplice = [];
    for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(o)) {     
      if (typeof v === 'object') {
        inner(v);
        if (!Object.keys(v).length) delete(o[k]);
      } else {
        if (dups.has(v)) {
          if (Array.isArray(o)) needSplice.unshift(k);
          else delete o[k];
        }
        else dups.add(v);
      }
    }
    for (const i of needSplice) o.splice(i, 1);
  }
  inner(obj);
}


removeDuplicateValues(data);

console.log(data);
```

I'll keep the original version that check keys & values here, it might be of use for other users searching..

You have two different keys `buttonText0` and `buttonText1`, so using your logic these should also appear but in your example your not including it.

But assuming your logic is correct, and you example output is wrong.

One way of doing this is flatten the Object into a a Map.. eg.  `{a:{b:4}}` becomes `key: 'a.b', value: 4`, and while doing this do a duplicate check.  Finally expand this out into your expected Object.

example..

```js
var data = {"modelhelloamazingIssue":{"modelhelloamazingIssueSevere":{"nameText":"Name","helloAnalysisType":["Normal","Mild","Moderate","Severe"],"helloText":"hello","abouthellosolo":"hello solo is a serious hello disorder that causes you to stop amazing during hello. It's important to understand the signs and symptoms.","noteText":"This is not a medical diagnosis and you may want to talk to your doctor.","buttonText0":"Next steps"},"modelhelloamazingIssueMild":{"nameText":"Name Example","helloAnalysisType":["Normal","Mild","Moderate","Severe"],"helloText":"hello","abouthellosolo":"My god this is so cool.","noteText":"This is not a medical diagnosis and you may want to talk to your doctor.","buttonText1":"Next steps"}}};

const gotKey = new Map();

function flat(o, root) {
  let ret = [];
  for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(o)) {
    if (typeof v === 'object' && !Array.isArray(v)) ret = [...ret, ...flat(v, root + k + '.')];
    else {
      const e = gotKey.get(k);
      if (!e || JSON.stringify(e) !== JSON.stringify(v)) {
        gotKey.set(k, v);
        ret.push([root + k, v]);
      }
    }
  }
  return ret;
}

const f = flat(data, '.');

const newObj = {};

for (const [k, v] of f) {
  const splits = k.split('.').filter(Boolean);
  let o = newObj;
  for (let ix = 0; ix < splits.length; ix ++)  {
    const s = splits[ix];
    if (ix === splits.length -1) o[s] = v;
    else {
      if (!o[s]) o[s] = {};
      o = o[s];
    }
  }
}


console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: Thanks for writing the solution but buttonText0 and buttonText1 both appears with same value. so only one of them should be present. I should delete the latter one buttonText1 should be removed. so that there is just one value that is unique for the whole json. That's what I would want. I hope I'm clear? the thing is I just want to remove all the duplicate values from my json.

Comment: @AshutoshSoni  Oh, so you don't care about the key at all, just values only.  In that case it should be even easier, use a Set while iterating.  I'm on mobile atm so will update when at Desktop..

Comment: Okay let me try. with set instead of a map

Comment: can you also update with set? I'm still not able to run it.

Comment: @AshutoshSoni  Back at PC now, just updated..